# Get Artifactory image regardless of tag in concourse

Tags: artifactory, concourse

When a Docker image with a certain name is pushed to Artifactory, then I want this to trigger my pipeline. I wan't this to occur regardless of tag since each push is a different tag. I tried using the artifactory resource, but no luck:
https://github.com/pivotalservices/artifactory-resource 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check out Artifactory User Plugins https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins

Comment: Post a minimal pipeline configuration that shows the problem and the error reported by Concourse. As-is, it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: @marco.m there is no error. The question is if it's possible. To make it more straight-forward "can one trigger a pipeline when an image is pushed, regardless of tag". Also, in the meantime I found out that the answer is 'No', unless one creates a custom-resource-type, which is what I ended up doing